# list of all jars for struts2 jquery application

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

Could anyone please list :

1. all the jars, javascript and Css files required for struts2 Jquery
   grid application. Also include jars if any, for  struts-2 jquery
   searchable grid.

   The application would make an ajax request with get method along
   with some request parameters, to an struts2 action class. The action
   class would populate an array-list that would be displayed using
   jquery grid in the jsp.
2. I see FilterDispatcher configured in web.xml is deprecated. Please
   also list the new class name to use for the corresponding jars and
   any other configuration is required for the application explained.
3. Please also list, changes, if any, in configuring action
   name/class/result tags in struts2. XML file and Action class.

I am trying to make simple struts2 jquery grid application from last 14 days. Example of google code doesn't list all jars required, so it dint work for . Latest struts2.3 jars when added gives class not found issues.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your all jar files to your server's runtime lib folder Java
 jars:

> Struts2.jars
>   Json.jar - for converting datas to json object
>   Jqgrid.jar
>   Jackson.jar
>   Javascript files:
>   Jquery.js
>   Jqgrid.js